# Specific variable names in general function - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I'm writing some code where I need to be able to load, unload, and reload modules on the fly (without closing the program). A big issue I'm running into is that there's no way to give unique names to the modules when I reload them - that is, I'm using a generalized function to reload them:

```
try {
      delete require.cache['./plugins/'+plugin];
      console.log("Reloading " + plugin + ".");
      var ??? = require('./plugins/'+plugin);

}
```

Given that this needs to work for an unspecified number of modules (and even modules that weren't included upon startup), how can I go about naming the new Require variable (currently ??? is a placeholder).

Thanks!

edit:

```
for (i in fs.readdirSync("./plugins")) {
  var pluginName = plugins[i].split('.')[0]
  plugins[pluginName] = pluginName;
  plugins[pluginName] = require("./plugins/" + pluginName);
  console.log(global.plugins[i].split('.')[0]);
};

console.log(testModule1.addi(2, 3));
console.log(testModule2.mult(2,3));
```

This is what I have right now and it doesn't work (testModule1.addi is just addition and testModule2.mult is just mulitplication). It works just fine when I do something like:

```
var testModule1 = require("./plugins/testModule1");
var testModule2 = require("./plugins/testModule2");
```

and then call the functions.

Comment: you can generate unique string and put the new loaded module into an object? `myObject[uniqueModuleName] = require(...)`

Comment: Why do you need a variable name in the first place? isn't everything you need is in require.cache already?

Comment: @TLJ - that's what I thought but I was testing it and without declaring variables it seems like the modules don't persist, or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have variable variable names like that, but fortunately you can use an object, and give it property names which are variable, something like this:

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var myModules = {};

var moduleName = 'module_' + uuid.v1();
myModules[moduleName] = require('./plugins/' + plugin);
```

This will guarantee you a unique name each time under `moduleName` that you can use.

Comment: this is my current attempt but it's just not working for me - maybe there's something else I'm missing?

Comment: Be more specific.  What's not working?   (Error message)